# React material ui Table adding some empty rows

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I using material UI Table, I tried some UI changes in my code in response to getting only one data and map in the table, but I fixed row length will be 5 remaining empty rows are not showing coming[image], I searched a lot place but can't find the result, please give a suggestion, any link it's very helpful Thanks for Help
https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-christian-lq6qj

[image]

Comment: Can you share the code? with the code, we can help you much better.

Comment: Code updated @jose Lora